# Can a hologram be programmed to emit a specific frequency of EM radiation?

Tags: electromagnetism, electromagnetic-radiation, hologram

Do holograms emit EM radiation, or is it possible to program a hologram to emit specific frequencies of EM? If possible, would it require light shining on the hologram to emit the EM?

I am asking this question to verify the science behind the "Food Freshness Card". From their website:

> The Food Freshness Card is a large hologram that is programmed with
> longitudinal electromagnetic waves. Our U.S. patented process allows
> us to modulate these longitudinal electromagnetic waves with different
> frequencies or frequency spectra. The modulations to these waves
> target specific strains of bacteria and mold which can inhibit their
> growth. The Food Freshness Card does not directly kill mold or
> bacteria but instead creates an environment that can slow their growth
> rate. Mold and bacteria are main causes of food spoilage, if you can
> inhibit the rate at which they grow, you can increase the shelf life
> of food.
> https://foodfreshnesscard.com/

I know there have been studies demonstrating EM radiation inhibiting bacterial growth, but I'm curious if this is actually possible with a hologram.

Comment: Well, x-rays can certainly kill bacteria (and humans in large enough doses). That description seems more marketing than science, so one should take it with a large dose of salt (which also inhibits bacterial growth).

Comment: Haha yes I am very skeptical but it would be cool if it actually worked. I remember reading about some material science innovations to inhibit bacteria on things like doorknobs. This sounds like a different concept though.

Comment: In their [site](https://foodfreshnesscard.com/) they claim: "*The Food Freshness Card does not directly kill mold or bacteria but instead creates an environment that can slow their growth rate*". They say it has been tested, but we don't have their data nor report on it

Comment: Buy one, test it, and get back to us with your results!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Holograms are just interference patterns, they can not produce any wavelengths they are not illuminated with. Further, the claim of it being "programmed with longitudinal electromagnetic waves" is pure technobabble. Longitudinal electromagnetic waves do not exist outside of certain physical systems.

Comment: Hi Christopher, would you mind expanding a little bit on why this is technobabble, just for posterity sake? I am curious exactly what their claim is, and why it's wrong

Comment: @JeremyGottfried They don't *have* an exact claim. That's the nature of technobabble, their technical claims literally have no meaning. Longitudinal EM waves don't exist, and if they did they wouldn't be something you'd "program" some material to emit a particular spectrum with. They're just magic words used to sell snake oil, from a mythology they've put together based loosely on ideas Tesla investigated about a century ago. Their other "products" mix in a bunch of quantum woo and other nonsense that uses lots of big words but similarly doesn't actually say anything.

Comment: @JeremyGottfried, because all electromagnetic waves are transverse waves, except for plasma waves, and electromagnetic waves in certain birefringent materials (see [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Longitudinal_wave#Electromagnetics)), which is certainly not the case, as that material would have to extend all through the food. It's a marketing stunt.

Comment: I wonder how that patent came through, shouldn't they have some criteria for not pateting stunts? And how about their [lab tests](https://foodfreshnesscard.com/laboratory-testing/)? Fake, or is it that the (transversal) EMs produced by the chip actually work somehow?

Comment: Yeah maybe there is another property in the tech that actually works, but it's impossible to know without a measure of statistical significance or experimental methods.

Comment: A patent is no indicator that an idea actually works, or is anything but nonsense, and they wouldn't even need to fake those "lab tests", just cherry-pick the results that came out in their favor. And I doubt it has any powered device embedded in it. From the patent, it is the material itself that "emits energy" after being "programmed": "A material placed on a receiving coil at the receiving electrode receives the resultant wave information programming the material to emit energy tuned to the natural frequencies of fresh foods."

Comment: For $85 bucks a piece they could even put an on-chip nuclear power plant on that thing... But the strongest fact that tells me it's fake is that they have been [advertised](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=DBcLk3smkYo) by Fox News Media :P

Answer (score 0):

From the [patent](https://patents.google.com/patent/US20170039404?oq=Food+Freshness+Card):

> 1. A food freshness card, comprising: ***a card substrate***; and ***a chip body*** attached to the card substrate, the chip body including a
>    material programmed via longitudinal carrier waves to emit energetic
>    information tuned for interaction with an organic structure in a piece
>    of food or liquid when the chip body is positioned proximate the piece
>    of food. (emphasis mine)
> 2. The food freshness card of claim 1, wherein the chip body is positioned on an exterior surface of the card substrate for direct contact with the piece of food.
> 3. The food freshness card of claim 1, wherein the programmed material has an effective strength of emission of approximately 5 feet in radius for indirect contact with the piece of food.

And then

> The ability to carry information through longitudinal wave carriers has until now, been underutilized. FIG. 1 shows an example of a ***Tesla coil***, waveform/signal generator connected to a spherical electrode as disclosed by Konstantin Meyl's book Scalar Wave Technology: Documentation for the Experimental-Kit for the Transmission of Electrical Scalar Waves. Configured correctly, the Tesla coil may produce a longitudinal wave which may carry energetic information over space. (emphasis mine)

So, its not the holograms that emit EM radiation, but instead the Tesla coil inside the built-in chip.

[image]

Comment: Ah so is this why it has a 1 year expiration date, because it's actually charged with a potential energy that emits gradually over a year?

Comment: Most likely yes, Fig. 9 shows a battery, but the text specifies nothing about it, so I wouldn't know exactly about that.

Comment: Konstantin Meyl is a prolific Tesla/free energy crackpot, and things like "a material programmed via longitudinal carrier waves to emit energetic information" are complete gibberish.

Comment: @ChristopherJamesHuff, lol, yes, couldn't put it better, but will try: "a complete *gibberic* marketing stunt".

Comment: @ChristopherJamesHuff I'm not sure he's a crackpot. If he can derive fundamental particles from field equations, when Quantum branch can only postulate or observe them. His model deserves more attention. He also explains the Tamarack mines mystery. And derived Schrödinger equation from his, so any proof of the former is also a proof of the latter.